# Unsaved records in rails and saved forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a record:

```
def new
  @usermodel = current_usermodel
  @profile = @usermodel.build_profile
end

def create
  @usermodel = current_usermodel
  @profile = @usermodel.create_profile(params[:profile]) 

  if not @profile.save
    flash.now[:error] = "Could not save your profile"
    render action: "new"
    return
  end
end
```

If it fails, it goes back to the new record page. However, I am looking for a way for the record to be temporarily saved even if it is not a valid record. How do I do this?

In addition to temporarily saving the record, can someone explain how the new form retains all the data from the previous submission?

Comment: 1) What does your form look like? It should work out of the box. 2) In `create` you're doing `@profile.save`, but `@profile` is defined nowhere. This code will never work. Did you mean `@profile = @usermodel.create_profile(params[:profile])`?

Comment: `However, I am looking for a way for the record to be temporarily saved even if it is not a valid record` - for how long. Is it just to display the form again with the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: You have couple of bugs in your code, I let myself assume that those were typing error. If not, this answer should help you understand what those errors were.

I also assumed you want to "save" the model just so you can redisplay it with error.

It is pretty simple really. Firstly the new action:

```
def new
  @usermodel = current_usermodel
  @profile = @usermodel.build_profile
end
```

With `build_profile` you are creating new model, but only within server's memory. Object is not saved in the database at this point. You are rendering the form, and form_builder uses this memory-only model to populate all the fields with right value (usually they are blank). As soon as the form is rendered, Rails replies to html request and destroys the controller, together with all your in-memory objects stored as instance_variables for this controller.

Now, within your create action (which should look like below):

```
def create
 @usermodel = current_usermodel
 @profile = @usermodel.build_profile(params[:profile]) 

 if @profile.save
   ...
 else
   flash.now[:error] = "Could not save your profile"
   render :new
 end
end
```

You should use `build_profile` again here. Create tries to save it, so your code does two db calls. Again, it will create a memory-only model, however this time you populate the attributes passed from the form by passing `params[:profile]` to it. At this point you have valid/invalid object in the memory, which contains all the submitted params. Whether it is saved to the database or not makes no difference here. If you know `render :new`, it will render `new` view, which has the form which is being build on `@profile` object. Since you defined this object within this action, no error is raised and all is ok.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this issue would be to remove the validations and use an after_update callback to run the validations after update rather than on create. There are also methods you can use to skip validations. [ActiveRecord Validations Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Also, `@usermodel.create_profile(params[:profile])` is not set to the instance variable `@profile`, but you're asking wether `@profile` is not saved. `@profile` will never be saved, so will always follow this branch of logic.

The form posts the contents of the form to a url. In rails, the params hash is used to store these posted values. Rails is smart enough to refill the fields matching the params key to the form field name.

Answer (score 0):

To save temporarlly bad records, you can use sessions with [redis-rails](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails) for exemple

```
session[:profile] = params[:profile]
```

Then to basically explain the process of form submission, your form values are send to the action create which instanciate your profile before saving it. If it does not fullfit the needs of the validations, rails keeps the object in an instance variable which is sent to the view, hence your form

Note:

1 .Your create method has something wrong, @profile will always be equal to nil, you need to set it before calling with something like :

```
@profile = @usermodel.profile
```

1. I advise you to use a [nested form](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) in this case